# Getting non-unique values from a django query

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm writing a script where I want to get every occurrence of a value, from visited sites.

First I get sites visited:

```
sd = SessionData.objects.filter(session_id__mlsession__platform__exact=int('2'))
result =  sd.values('last_page')
```

I then get the values that I'm expecting:

```
[{'last_page': 10L}, {'last_page': 4L}, {'last_page': 10L}]
```

With that, I want the page with 10L as an id to have double the weight of 4L, since it's appearing two times.

I try to get the values from the list:

```
wordData = KeywordData.objects.filter(page_id__in=result)
```

but then I only get unique values:

```
[<KeywordData: 23>, <KeywordData: 24>, <KeywordData: 8>]
```

where my wanted outcome would be:

```
[<KeywordData: 23>, <KeywordData: 24>, <KeywordData: 8>, <KeywordData: 23>, <KeywordData: 24>]
```

The only way I've managed to not get a unique list is by iterating through a for-loop but that isn't really an option since the data I'm dealing with has millions of entries.

Is the "__in" filter in django made to only return unique entries? Is there a way that I can get the right output the "django"-way?

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT: The relevant models:**

```
class KeywordData(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, db_column='page_id', related_name='page_pageid', default=None)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Page, db_column='site_id', related_name='page_siteid', default=None)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class MLSession(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, null=True, db_column='session_id')
    platform = models.IntegerField(choices=PLATFORM_CHOICE)
    visitor_type = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class SessionData(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, db_column='session_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, db_column='site_id', db_index=True, default=None, null=True)
    last_page = models.ForeignKey(Page, db_column='last_page_id', default=None, null=True, related_name='session_last_page')
    first_page = models.ForeignKey(Page, db_column='first_page_id', default=None, null=True, related_name='session_first_page')
```

*The tables **Session** and **Page** are only referred to in terms of their ids, which are auto-incremented.*

I want to look at the last page of the session, thus only taking in the last_page_id, and get the keywords from the respective page. If the same page is often the last page, I want to add more weight, as previously stated.

Let me know if some more information is needed, and thanks again!

Comment: Please show your `SessionData` and `KeywordData` models

Comment: I have added them now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the "__in" filter in django made to only return unique entries?

The `__in` filter in Django maps directly to the `IN` condition in SQL, and its behavior is as you've observed.

If you want duplicate rows you should probably reframe your query as an SQL `JOIN`. You didn't post your models so I'm forced to guess here, but the following Django query should give you what you want:

```
KeywordData.objects.filter(page__session_last_page__session_id__mlsession__platform=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By doing this, I can get all of the keywords from the session that use platform no. 2, but I only want the keywords from the last page of the flow. Do you know about any simple way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: @HelgaSigurðardóttir: If you specify that you want to `JOIN` on the `session_last_page` field that should get you what you want. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary of keywords keyed by the page id:

```
from collections = defaultdict

result =  sd.values_list('last_page', flat=True)
keywords_by_page_id = defaultdict(list)
for k in KeywordData.objects.filter(page_id__in=result):
    keywords_by_page_id[k.page_id].append(k)
```

Then loop through the `result` to build your required output.

```
out = []
for x in results:
    out += keywords_by_page_id[x]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's true that the output is not unique anymore but I get  [<KeywordData: 10>, <KeywordData: 4>, <KeywordData: 10>] so it's taking the same ids as the last page ids instead of it's own. I will look more closely into in_bulk and see if I can find a solution, thanks!

Comment: Oh... `in_bulk` isn't going to work, because `result` is a list of `page_id`s, not KeywordData ids. You should be able to get it to work by creating your own dictionary keyed by `page_id`s

Comment: Thank you for all your help, but this assigns only one keyword to each page_id. :) For `page_id = 4` I want to get `keyword_id = 8` and for `page_id = 10` I want to get `keyword_id = 23, keyword_id = 24`. However, with this solution, I get `{10L: <KeywordData: 24>, 4L: <KeywordData: 8>}`.

So now it's skipping word ids instead of page ids! I've been trying to crack this but wanted to respond in case you could easily see the solution to this particular problem.

Comment: I've had one last attempt, this time using values for the dictionary lists. If that doesn't work, then I'm going to admit defeat because I can't get my head round your models.

Comment: Thanks! :) I actually managed to get the right list in the beginning with a two-line for-loop, but was worried about complexity because in the end I have millions of entries (not only three, this is the testing database). 